# copy and paste information, from specific columns of the first 6 rows, from one work book to another, using excel-vba macros

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

So, i need to copy information from specific columns of one workbook and paste this information in specific columns of another workbook. I have done this successfully by writing the following code:

```
Sub test()

 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim mysh As Worksheet
 Dim sourceColumn As Range
 Dim targetColumn As Range
 Dim i As Long


 Set wb = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm")

    'Above code is same as yours

    Set mysh = wb.Sheets(1) 'if only one sheet, use loop otherwise


           mysh.Range("J1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Date



Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("D")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("B")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn


Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("G")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("D")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("J")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("E")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn


Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("K")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("F")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn


Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("L")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("G")

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

**What i specifically want to do is to copy and paste this information from only the first 6 visible records of WorkbookA.These records are not from ( cell numbers 1 to 6)**

**At the moment information from all rows are getting copied and pasted.**

**How do i modify the code in an appropriate manner to perform this correctly?**

Comment: What rows do you want to copy and paste? The first 6 rows in Workbook A?

Comment: yes specific information from first 6 rows.

Comment: Do you want to the copy the entire rows or just the cells that intersect with your 6 columns?

Comment: @JLILIAman please take a look at my code, its not the entire rows, only specific information.

Comment: It's not clear how do you want to paste that specific information? Can you provide a sample of your desired output vs your input?

Comment: For example, i need to copy information from column D in Workbook A to column B in Workbook B. I need to do this only for the first 6 rows.

Comment: Got you! I'm sorry. First 6 cells regardless if they're blank or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `columns` use `range` to define the number of cells that you want to copy.

```
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("D1:D6")
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B6")
sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
```

Using `Columns` is not recommend because it's a time-consuming task for VBA. A single column can be a collection +1M cells. That will take Excel a lot of time to process.

`sourceColumn` and `targetColumn` need to be defined as `range`

**Edit 1:** Now that you have filtering according to your comments, you might want to try this:

Define a variable to get the last row number of data from the sourcecolumn.
Something like for column D:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
With Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(XlUp).Row
End With
```

Now we're going to get the range of the visible cells from the source column. This the step that will just the visible cells after you apply the filter.(**I've excluded D1 because it should be the header of your column**)

```
Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("WorkbookA.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range("D2:D" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

We'll simply run through the cell collection of sourcecolumn and tell to paste it just 6 cells in the target workbook:

```
Dim counter as integer: counter = 1
With  Workbooks("WorkbookB.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
For each cell in sourcecolumn
if counter = 7 then
Exit for
end if 
.Range("B" & counter) = cell.value
counter = counter + 1 
Next
End With
'Counter = 0 do forget to reset it if you're going to use it for the other columns
```

**Tested and working :)**

Comment: There is a problem. For the workbook A, the range for a column does not start at 1, since i have performed filtering and sorting.

Comment: After you apply your first, you're always get 6 cells?

Comment: No i get more than 6. I get 123 cells per column.

Comment: So you want to get the first visible 6 columns after you apply the filter?

Comment: so,  its not possible to give a range from 1 to 6. Ideally the macro should be able to detect the cell numbers of the 1st 6 rows since they do not range from 1 to 6.

Comment: You should've said that from the start ! ;)

Comment: True i should have. I will edit it in the question body.

Comment: No problem @melissa! Do not hesitate to ask any questions on SO! We're here to learn and help!

Comment: Its not working, the information is not getting pasted.

Comment: where in my code should i add the information in edit 1?

Comment: I think I've made some typos with the last segement of code can you try it now and I have edited it!

Comment: No error message is displayed. But the information is not pasted.
Did it work for you, Aman?

Comment: Yes, it did work for me. Would you please paste your code so I can examine it? http://www.ipaste.org/

Comment: Yes I know.
But its not getting applied for the col D and B

Comment: ok i will pasted the code for you.
its the same code you gave me i havent changed it

Comment: i pasted the code. please have a look and let me know

Comment: There is a missing dot before cells in `LastRow = Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(XlUp).Row` -> `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(XlUp).Row`

Comment: I want to implement this for the other columns.
I should repeat and modify the code accordingly?

Comment: Yes, you can @melissa :D